# How to show suggestion on sap.m.input control in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5, hana

I am new to SAPUI5 and I have a requirement where I have to show a suggestion on sap.m.input control. I am trying to do it with a suggest event, but I am not getting any suggestion and no error either. 
As far as I know, suggest event will show the suggestion on user input. If my code is going wrong then please let me know what I have to correct to make it work.

XML:

```xml
<Label id='idDocLbl' text="" />
<Input id = "iddocNo" width="450px" 
          placeholder = "Enter Doc No ..."
          showSuggestion="true"
          showValueHelp = "true"
          valueHelpRequest = "handleDocValueHelp"
          enabled="true" change = "handleDocChange"
          valueState = "None"
          suggest = "handleDocSuggest">
</Input>
```

Controller:

```js
handleDocSuggest: function (oEvent) {
        var that = this;
        var inputId = oEvent.getSource().getId();
        var displayModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("displayModel");
        var oSource = displayModel.getProperty("/sourceView");
        var systemId = displayModel.getProperty("/systemId");
        var compCode = displayModel.getProperty("/compCode");
        var type = displayModel.getProperty("/type");
        var prdId = this.getView().byId("idPrdid").getValue();
        var viewname = oSource + "HDView";
        var viewDependent = '';
        var docField = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("configModel").getProperty("/docField");
        sap.ui.getCore().getModel("displayModel").setProperty("/docField", docField);
        var docid = this.getView().byId("iddocNo");
        docid.setModel(displayModel);

        oEvent.oSource.bindAggregation("suggestionItems", "/" + oSource, new sap.ui.core.ListItem({
            text: "{" + docField + "}",
            growing: true,
            key: "{" + docField + "}"
        }));
        that._handleSuggest(oEvent, docField, viewDependent);
    },

    _handleSuggest: function (osuggest, viewkey, viewDependent) {
        var lValue = osuggest.getParameter("suggestValue").toUpperCase();
        var displayModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("displayModel");
        var oSource = displayModel.getProperty("/sourceView");
        var systemId = displayModel.getProperty("/systemId");
        var compCode = displayModel.getProperty("/compCode");
        var type = displayModel.getProperty("/type");
        var prdId = this.getView().byId("idPrdid").getValue();
        var filterArray = [];
        filterArray.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter(viewkey, sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, lValue));
        filterArray.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("SYSTEM_ID", "EQ", systemId));
        filterArray.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("COMPANY_CD", "EQ", compCode));
        filterArray.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("DATA_CRCTN_TYP_CD", "EQ", type));
        filterArray.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("NGTL_WORKFLOW_STATUS", "NE", "Y"));
        if (viewDependent.length > 0) {
            var inputdepend_value;
            inputdepend_value = this.getView().byId("idSystemId").getValue();
            var oDepFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(viewDependent, sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, inputdepend_value);
            var oDepFinal = [];
            oDepFinal.push(oDepFilter);
            oDepFinal.push(oFilter);

            osuggest.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(oDepFinal);
        } else {
            osuggest.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter([filterArray]);
        }
    },
```

Comment: What value does osuggest in _handleSuggest function has? Is it undefined or null?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you are not getting the suggestion items to show. You seem to have the items in a model already so you can set the aggregation directly to the xml element.

```
   <Input id = "iddocNo" width="450px" 
          placeholder = "Enter Doc No ..."
          showSuggestion="true"
          showValueHelp = "true"
          valueHelpRequest = "handleDocValueHelp"
          enabled="true" change = "handleDocChange"
          valueState = "None"
          suggest = "handleDocSuggest"
          suggestionItems="{displayModel>/sourceView}">
          <suggestionItems>
                <core:Item key="{key}" text="{Name}" />
          </suggestionItems>
  </Input>
```

This way as long as you have itmes in the model path you set you should get the list to pop up. The key in

```
<suggestionItems>
    <core:Item key="{key}" text="{Name}" />
</suggestionItems>
```

is passed in the event and you can use fron there.

Hope im helping.